# select single email instead of whole thread

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I have a script that brings in my email body from Gmail into a google-sheet cell, basically I search for a starred email and bring it in at the end I unstar it (it shouldn't come in again when running next time). However I'm having a problem that it brings in the whole thread of the email. To clarify: My gmail settings is set to "Conversation view Off" and that's how I see it in my inbox, every msg separately, but it looks like in the Gmail API its still stored as one long thread...
How can I import only one msg without the whole thread?
(The thread isn't a real conversation, its just an automated email from same sender and same subject, this is why its considered by Gmail as a thread, so if there's a way to stop that, that will also help.)

My code is below.

```
var SEARCH_QUERY = "label:web is:unread to:me is:starred";

function getEmails_(q) {
var emails = [];
emails.length = 0;
var threads = GmailApp.search(q);
for (var i in threads) {
var msgs = threads[i].getMessages();
for (var j in msgs) {
emails.push([msgs[j].getPlainBody().replace(/<.*?>/g, '\n')
.replace(/^\s*\n/gm, '').replace(/^\s*/gm, '').replace(/\s*\n/gm, '\n')]);

msgs[j].unstar().refresh();
}
}
return emails; 
}




function appendData_(sheet, array2d) {

sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, array2d.length, 
array2d[0].length).setValues(array2d);
}



function saveEmails() {
var array2d = getEmails_(SEARCH_QUERY);
if (array2d) {
appendData_(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Web 
Email'), array2d);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [GmailApp documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app)--this contains an explanation of the available methods and the type of object they return. You are trying to get a GmailMessage object, but GmailApp.search() returns an array of GmailThread objects by design. I don't believe it's possible to search Gmail for a specific message--as your code shows, you can get the array of threads returned by search and loop through them, using getMessages() to get specific messages.

Comment: So is it possible to get only the last msg of the thread, so I'll basically set the trigger when new email arrives, and it will each time take only the last msg of the thread,

Comment: You will still need to fetch all messages in the thread first, but it's trivial to get the last message afterwards by selecting the 0th message; I'm not sure if this date sorting is part of the specification, but it's at least reliable enough that [the documentation implies its use](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#createDraftReply(String)).